# Cannot able to Run Erlang in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, erlang

I have setup Erlang in Eclips , but somehow it's not able to make .beam files and execute code.

Here are the details of my Run Configuration.

[image: Setup 1]

[image: Setup 2]

[image: Setup 3]

[image: Setup 4]

when I am running inside Eclipse Console I am getting following Error:

```
Eshell V5.9
(erlide@Sujoy-VAIO)1> c(geometry).
geometry.erl:none: no such file or directory
error
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not find your source code.

Not sure, but I think you should define your source code directory in the variable "working directory" in the run time configuration panel.

Answer (score 0):

You skipped the screenshot with "Code path" tab and I believe that's where the way to fix this issue is.

By the way I'd highly recommend using basho's [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar) to compile Erlang projects instead of relying on IDE. Also I'd recommend to check out [SublimErl](https://github.com/ostinelli/SublimErl) as an alternative to Erlide.